Ways to implement AI table search
I am new to this matter, so I ask for your help. I have a table with 3 columns: ID, title and description.I want to implement an AI search through data and return ID of the record, if one was found. Searching by equality, occurrence or full text doesn't work for me (not in all cases) and here's why. For example, I'm looking for a "working days reference" - for this request I should get a "working calendar" Because the description states that the current entity contains data about "working days and weekends in a year." How I can implement such a thing on the most minimalistic models? I wanna create local solutions without internet access after build
What i already did:
I'm just comparing the required query string with the description and title columns, using ollama and gemma2b (python) I have more than 10,000 records in the table and doing this row by row is very expensive. Loading all the data into the model may be stupid and such a long process will simply refuse to work.
At the end I want to make it simple API Service, and i know how to do this, but i have problem with understanding AI

It seems that you want to implement a search based on the similarity between the query and what is in the table, but this "similarity" is not well defined. In the end, search engines also don't make an exact word search. They probably use different heuristics. Maybe you can create an embedding for the query and then use these embedding like in a space where close embedding are more similar than distant ones. Also, when you say "I'm just comparing the required query string with the description and title columns", what do you mean by "compare"? Do you even need a model to compare?
